# How can I find the selected item in a QTreeWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, events, kde-plasma, treewidget

I have a class that inherits QTreeWidget. How can I find the currently selected row?
Usually I connect signals to slots this way:

```
connect(myButton, SIGNAL(triggered(bool)), this, SLOT(myClick()));
```

However, I can't find anything similar for `QTreeWidget->QTreeWidgetItem`.
The only way I found is to redefine the mousePressEvent of the QTreeWidget class like this:

```
void MyQTreeWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e){
    QTreeView::mousePressEvent(e);
    const QModelIndex index = indexAt(e->pos());
    if (!index.isValid())
    {
    const Qt::KeyboardModifiers modifiers = QApplication::keyboardModifiers();
    if (!(modifiers & Qt::ShiftModifier) && !(modifiers & Qt::ControlModifier))
    clearSelection();
    }
 }
```

I didn't try it yet. Is the only solution or is there any easier way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the itemClicked() signal will miss any selection changes made using the keyboard. I'm assuming that's a bad thing in your case.

Comment: it's perfect, I only need to click on the QTreeWidget :)

Answer (score 17):

Dusty is almost correct. But the itemSelectionChanged signal will not tell you which item is selected.

```
QList<QTreeWidgetItem *> QTreeWidget::selectedItems() const
```

will give you the selected item(s).

So, connect a slot to the itemSelectionChanged signal, then call selectedItems() on the tree widget to get the selected item(s).

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  It even says so in the documentation that I linked to.  Nice catch.

Answer (score 3):

you can simply use this :

```
QString word = treeWidget->currentItem()->text(treeWidget->currentColumn());
```

to get your text in the variable word.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation [here](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/qtreewidget.html) it appears that you should connect the *QTreeWidget* *[itemSelectionChanged()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/qtreewidget.html#itemSelectionChanged)* signal to a slot in your class.  That will tell you which *QTreeWidgetItem* was selected which is what I believe you want.

Answer (score 0):

ooops, I've solved simply using this:

```
connect(this,SIGNAL(itemClicked(QTreeWidgetItem*, int)), SLOT(mySlot()));
```

however thanks for replies :D