# QTreeWidgetItem: How can I get the selected item?

Tags: c++, qt, vector, qt4, qtreewidget

I am currently a student programmer using Qt to build a GUI inteface at work and I am currently running into a problem finding a solution in the [Qt Documentation On the QTreeWidgetItem](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtreewidget.html#currentItem). I currently have an interface that has buttons to edit, delete, and copy instances in my `QTree`. It might be important for you to understand the way my tree is populated. The items displayed in the `QTree` are dynamically appended from a vector in this way.

```
void InjectionGUI::addInjections_Clicked() //creates a new instance of injections
{
    InjectionDialog newAddInjectionDialog; //where my dialog opens for user input
    InjectionData defaultValues; 
    newAddInjectionDialog.setData(defaultValues);
            if(newAddInjectionDialog.exec() == QDialog::Accepted)//a check data returns either Accepted or rejected 
            {
               qTableInjectionData.append(newAddInjectionDialog.transInjectionData); //this appends the valid data from the injection dialog to the vector qTableInjectionData
                ui->injectionTreeWidget->clear();
                for (int i=0; i < qTableInjectionData.size(); i++) // here I add the data from the vector to the tree widget.
                    {
                    InjectionData temp = qTableInjectionData.at(i);
                        QString injectionType;
                        QString tmpStr;
                        int column = 0;

                        //need sorting solution(still working on this)
                        if(temp.particleInjectionActive == true) // this evaluates the injection types
                        {
                            if(temp.particleInjectionOrLiquidDroplets == true)
                            {
                                injectionType += "(LD)";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                injectionType += "(P)";
                            }
                        }
                        if(temp.fluidInjectionActive == true)
                        {
                            injectionType += "(F)";
                        }
                        QTreeWidgetItem *qTreeWidgetItemInjectionData = new QTreeWidgetItem(ui->injectionTreeWidget); //Here data is added into rows from each instance of injection dialog found in vector
                        qTreeWidgetItemInjectionData->setText(column++, tmpStr.setNum(i));
                        qTreeWidgetItemInjectionData->setText(column++, temp.lineEditInjectionName);
                        qTreeWidgetItemInjectionData->setText(column++, injectionType);
                        qTreeWidgetItemInjectionData->setText(column++, tmpStr.setNum(temp.lineEditParitcleVelocity));
                        qTreeWidgetItemInjectionData->setText(column++, tmpStr.setNum(temp.lineEditFluidVelocity));
                        qTreeWidgetItemInjectionData->setText(column++, tmpStr.setNum(temp.lineEditParticleMassFlow));
                        qTreeWidgetItemInjectionData->setText(column++, tmpStr.setNum(temp.lineEditFluidMassFlow));
                        qTreeWidgetItemInjectionData->setText(column++, temp.lineEditComment);
                    }
            }
}
```

Now I really need a way to find out which item the user has selected in the `QTree` so that I can have it deleted from the Vector. My psuedo is to identify which row has been selected, confirm delete, delete itemAt(item selected), reassign ID column; because each instance is assigned a number in this column. I was looking over this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334952/how-can-i-find-the-selected-item-in-a-qtreewidget), posted three years ago; but it mostly just refers back to the documentation that I have already been reviewing. Plus, the answer that was selected seems extremely inconclusive as the other answer seem to have been on the right track. I understand that this answer might be right in front of me here; but what can i say, noobs will be noobs and I am having a hard time understanding the implementation. Please only leave productive feedback as I am only interested in learning and accomplishing this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to obtain the `selectionModel`, then the selected indices and then iterate over them:

```
treeWidget->selectionModel()->selection();
  auto idx = sel.indexes();
  foreach(auto index, idx) {
    camModel_->removeRow(index.row());
  }
}
```

`selectionModel` is in `QAbstractItemModel`. Note the C++11 `auto`.

Comment: Im giving this a try now; maybe I should instead have an independent connect statement to return the item selected so I can reuse for other functions?

Comment: @WylieCoyoteSG. Please enlighten me. What is an `independent connect statement`?

Comment: I have buttons for each function I would like to use, delete, copy, and edit. Each of these will have connect statement, but perhaps I should have another connect statement for the tree widget Item clicked/selected? Something more like connect Item Selected to pointer function which returns pointer to item selected. then using connect statements from copy, edit, and delete. Take *Item Selected and do stuff.

Comment: In Addition, connect statements manually connect signals and slots.

Comment: @WylieCoyoteSG. Just connect some signal to a function that performs the above. Replace `camModel_->removeRow` with whatever your model is supposed to do with the indices.

Comment: OK, This seems like a great place to start my item selected function; thanks for your help.

Comment: **This code snippet is blatantly broken.** The first statement `treeWidget->selectionModel()->selection();` trivially reduces to a noop and the closing braces are unmatched. Even were these syntactic and semantic failures *not* the case, however, this code snippet would still be overkill by several lines. Why? Because calling the `QTreeWidget::selectedItems()` method, which directly yields a list over the currently selected tree items, is significantly simpler than begging bureaucratic middle-men like `QAbstractItemView` and `QItemSelectionModel` for assistance. `</sigh>`